# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in java

Tags: java, arrays

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ws1qn2 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int a;
        int d;
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of characters the word has: ");
        d=input.nextInt();
        a=d-1;
        char word[]=new char[a];
        for (int b=0;b!=a;b++)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter character no."+b+1);
            String str;
            str=input.next();
            char c=str.charAt(b);
            word[a-b]=c;
        }
        for (char reverse : word)
        {
            System.out.print(reverse);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what happens when I run the program:

```
Please enter the number of characters the word has: 
3
Please enter character no.01
s
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at ws1qn2.main(ws1qn2.java:22)

Process completed.
```

Help? It looks like a stack overflow, but I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Looks like an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` to me ...

Comment: Yeah.. I'd like to know how this is a stack overflow..

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is as follows: You're initializing word to be an array of length `d-1`, in your case 2, however Java Arrays are 0 indexed so an array of length 2 only goes up to index 1:

Then you are attempting to access `word[2]` to set it to `c`, which drives your array index out of bounds

Comment: In addition I think an ouotOfBounds will be thrown here `char c=str.charAt(b);`.

Answer (score 1):

`str` is read each time and its size seems to be expected to be 1. You should not do this `char c=str.charAt(b);` but instead you should always get he first char `char c=str.charAt(0);`

Another issue when b is zero, `a-b` is `a` and thus `words[a-b]` is out of bounds for the array `words` that is of size `a`. You should subtract 1 from the index here: `words[a-b-1]`